# How to know which code caused a trap in xv6 when debugging?

Tags: operating-system, xv6

Here is what I suppose: When the code causes a trap (system call or exceptions), xv6 will replace the registers with certain values to transfer the control to `alltraps()`, in which `trap()` is called.

But sometimes xv6 runs into `trap()` out of my expectation, and I want to know why it got into this trap. When debugging, after I set a break point in `trap()` and xv6 stopped here, I can only see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWI1l.png) in the debugger (I'm using CLion). In the call stack, the bottom stack frame is `alltraps()` so I can't find out when and why the trap is caused.

I want to find out in which file, at which line the trap is caused for a certain call of `trap()`. Is this possible?

Comment: You can add temporary `cprintf` statements to the `trap` function. For example `cprintf( "Handling trap number %d\n", tf->trapno )`. Note that the [default](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/34f060c3dcf3bf3dde683df9ff9872bc9f1d5d14/trap.c#L82) case already prints an "unexpected trap" error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will examine `trap()` code more carefully, you will see that it also handles hardware interrupts (timer, ide and so on).

```
     36 void                                                                            
     37 trap(struct trapframe *tf)                                                      
     38 {                                                                               
     39   if(tf->trapno == T_SYSCALL){                                                  
              ...                                                
     47   }                                                                             
     48                                                                                 
     49   switch(tf->trapno){                                                           
     50   case T_IRQ0 + IRQ_TIMER:                                                      
     51     if(cpuid() == 0){                                                           
     52       acquire(&tickslock);                                                      
     53       ticks++;                                                                  
     54       wakeup(&ticks);                                                           
     55       release(&tickslock);                                                      
     56     }                                                                           
     57     lapiceoi();                                                                 
     58     break;                                                                      
     59   case T_IRQ0 + IRQ_IDE:                                                        
             ...
```

So what are you seeing is hardware interrupt coming and processor transfers control to one of the IDT vectors then to `alltraps` then to `trap()`. Most likely you are facing timer interrupt, which is used for context switch.

> I want to find out in which file, at which line the trap is caused for a certain call of trap(). Is this possible?

No it is not possible, because this is a hardware event and it has no relation to source code.